# Related model data getting saved even if fields are blank

Tags: cakephp

I have a cakephp (2.2) app that has a expense model and a cashfloat model. The Expense model has a HasOne relationship with the cashFloat model and the cashFloat model belongs to the Expense model.

I have a form that represents the "expense" with a single cash float field.

My issues is that when the expense is saved, if the cash float field is empty a record with a null value is still created in the cashFloats table. How can I avoid this? I only want to create the cash floats record if the cash float field is not blank.

Is a beforesave() on the cashFloat model that checks if its empty the best way to go? (I've had a break from cake for the last few months so apologies if I'm missing something very simple).

Models : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ba48b84bddcc4dd23a3

Comment: I've tried the beforeSave method but returning false if the field is empty stops the form from submitting and returns errors.

Comment: Any code you can show us?

Comment: Please post your Models and the method that does the saving...

Comment: @mark the forms pretty big, exactly what would you like to see? I just dont want to create a record for something that doesnt exist.

Comment: Added link to models.

Comment: You need to be careful. This will most likely break if you want to save another field and don't even pass this field. Only trigger those rules or beforeSave modifications if the array key is present in the data array!

Comment: @mark can you offer a solution? I dont want to fill my cashFloats table with null values just because the field is present on the form. Do I need to add some sort of check within the expense controller for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by unsetting the data array key for the cashFloat amount via the beforeValidate() callback. Hope this helps someone.

```
public function beforeValidate(){
    if(empty($this->data['CashFloat']['amount'])){
        unset($this->data['CashFloat']['amount']);
    }
    return true; //this is required, otherwise validation will always fail
}
```